# Ubuntu 14.10 won't upgrade to 15.04

Tags: upgrade

Hello I am running ubuntu 14.10 on a Toshiba Portege R930 with core i3 intel, 8GB of RAM and a 320GB HDD. I also use Gnome flashback Metacity. My problem is when I try to upgrade to 15.04 from the terminal I (after some updating) get this message:

```
Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/appgrid/appdata.py", line 207, in <module>
    rebuild_db()
  File "/usr/share/appgrid/appdata.py", line 174, in rebuild_db
    website text);''')
sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/appgrid/appdata.py", line 207, in <module>
    rebuild_db()
  File "/usr/share/appgrid/appdata.py", line 174, in rebuild_db
    website text);''')
sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
```

I am wondering what the source of the error is and how to fix it. Also if I run software updater (even when checking for any new ubuntu version is selected in the software manager) I get the your software is up to date message. Could someone please help?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 is not yet released, so off topic here, try asking on [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu) where questions like this are on topic.

Comment: Oh sorry, it is supposed to be released today though? it must be later today. Thanks!

Comment: I have not seen the official release note yet.  Once its released you should see the download [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).  Should be out later today though as you can see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseSchedule)

Comment: You can only upgrade from one release to the next or to the next LTS release.

Comment: "sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error". Your hard disk seems to be damaged.